# Removing right-click menu option in Xubuntu/XFCE - Imagemagick

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, menu, imagemagick

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04. Every time I right click on a picture I get an option to use Imagemagick at the top. I would like to get rid of it.

I've tried removing display-im6.q16.desktop from the ~./config/mimeapps.list file. No luck.

There seem to be imagemagick .desktop files all over the place. I have no idea how the system is picking them up.

Comment: Okay. This is Xubuntu 20.04. The file display-im6.q16.desktop exists in several different locations across the file system. It's in /usr/share/applications, ~./local/share/applications, ~./gnome/apps, and a few directories that begin with /proc/1088. Probably in a few other locations too but I gave up waiting for the file search to finish.

Comment: It's a clean install. I uninstalled Ristretto and installed gthumb. I think imagemagick is installed in the background with any Ubuntu version, anyway.